# How to filter the blank rows with query function in Pandas condition with multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to filter my dataframe with the condition that it should `filter` the rows based on column condition. so i want to `filter` all the rows which doesn't have any blank value in column (`AD65`) and also to `filter` only those rows which has value `"Machine"` in column `B14`. I tried with `Query` function in `Pandas` and is returning Empty data frame.
I have tried filtering for non empty value condition and that's works okay.

Here is my sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['AD65', 'W70', 'B14'])
print(df.query("AD65 == 'notnull' & B14 == 'Machine'"))
```

I have tried this with boolean variable able to filter the rows with following code@

```
# filters the rows in dataframe with non blank values for column AD65
df_non_blank = df[df.AD65.notnull()]
print(df_non_blank)

df_MP_4 = df[df['B14'] == 'Machine']
print(df_MP_4)
```

But I am not able to figure out how to put the & condition to filter the above two.

**Note**: After filtering my rows based on above condition i want to iterate all my rows with for loop.
Can i put the above filter condition in my while loop??

I am confused with the pandas dataframe structure and condition and loop functions for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from the documentation of [pandas.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

> `DataFrame.query(expr, inplace=False, **kwargs)[source]`
> Query the columns of a DataFrame with a boolean expression.
>
> Parameters `expr str`: The query string to evaluate.
>
> if one of your columns is called a a and you want to sum
> it with b, your query should be `a a` + b.

So, you need to add enclose the column name by a pair of `
And also, 'notnull' is going to be considered a string value, not a function, so you need to change your code as:

```
print(df.query("`AD65`.notna() & `B14` == 'Maschine'"))
```

Comment: Ah I see. It works as expected now thanks :)                                                                         One more question how can i put this condition into my while loop?

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked, Talking about loop, DataFrame Query is meant to create masking, you can refer the documentation, I have provided in the answer.